# Passing Value from One Fragment To Another returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

In my Xamarin android app I have a two fragments A & B, A sends a value of string name to Fragment B like below,

```
mFragmentA = new FragmentA();

string name = "john";

 var fragmenttransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmenttransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FragmentContainer, mFragmentA, "mFragmentA");
            fragmenttransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
            fragmenttransaction.Commit();

  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("namekey", name);
            mFragmentA.Arguments = bundle;
 return mFragmentA;
```

In fragment B in the oncreateView I try to retrieve it as below,

```
Bundle bundle = this.Arguments;
var name= bundle.GetString("namekey", "Default Value"); //NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION
```

Am getting a null reference exception on the name variable. Why? How do i get the string name in fragment A and assign it to name variable in Fragment B?

Comment: Cause you first replace fragments, and then put bundle inside a fragment, which is already on screen

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, You beat me to it :P, this is the answer btw not a comment.

Comment: Am not understanding, should i run the putstring() before the transaction?

Comment: Yes, and I don't get why you're returning the Fragment, what do you need to return the fragment for? You may put the fragment replacement in the function in which you receive the fragmentA you create in this code fragment.

Comment: Still not working geting null reference on both bundle object and name object.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you first replace fragments, and then put bundle inside a fragment, which is already on screen, here you are @jobbert xD

Answer (score 0):

### Change your code as below

```
    mFragmentA = new FragmentA();

    string name = "john";

     var fragmenttransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.PutString("namekey", name);
          mFragmentA.setArguments(bundle);


        fragmenttransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FragmentContainer, mFragmentA, "mFragmentA");
        fragmenttransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmenttransaction.Commit();


        return mFragmentA;
```

Comment: Didn't work Stiil getting Null Exception in Fragment B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. Before you commit fragment transaction. And after putting all your data to fragmentB object you should replace it with fragmentA.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.PutString("namekey", name);
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: Still get a Null Reference Exception on Using Fragment B. Should i use Fragment A to save to bundle or Fragment B?

Comment: You should save bundle (that code above) in FragmentA, then make transaction to replace your FragmentA to FragmentB.

Logic: FragmentA -> creating FragmentB, put there Data, replace FragmentA with FragmentB.
FragmentB->get data from bundle, after replace.

Comment: probably mFragmentA.Arguments = bundle; legit, because you use C# not Java :)

Comment: Could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the constructor or properties?

```
string name = "john";
mFragmentA = new FragmentA(name);

var fragmenttransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmenttransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FragmentContainer, mFragmentA, "mFragmentA");
        fragmenttransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmenttransaction.Commit();

 return mFragmentA;
```

The constructor will execute before the OnCreateView and OnCreate methods execute.

NOTE: In your code, there is no `FragmentB`. So this is really just passing data from the current Activity/Fragment to `FragmentA`(since that's what's getting instantiated).

Comment: Tried using properties but am getting weird unhanded exceptions in Xamarin which could be a bug also. In the mean time i've gone with shared preferences.

Comment: Must be something in your code. We use properties and constructors and they work perfectly fine in this scenario.